# Why is my local variable said to be unassigned when it is conditionally assigned?

Tags: variables, python-3.x, local

```
def get_date(date):
month = date[4:7] 
if month == "01":
    month_string = "January"
elif month == "02":
    month_string = "February"
elif month == "03":
    month_string = "March"
elif month == "04":
    month_string = "April"
elif month == "05":
    month_string = "May"
elif month == "06":
    month_string = "June"
elif month == "07":
    month_string = "July"
elif month == "08":
    month_string = "August"
elif month == "09":
    month_string = "September"
elif month == "10":
    month_string = "October"
elif month == "11":
    month_string = "November"
elif month == "12":
    month_string = "December"
return month_string
```

The variable 'date' is an input string in the form yyyy/mm/dd.

This function tests to see if the month from the input yyyy/mm/dd is one of those numbers and assigns a string to that number value. Shouldn't this decision structure assign a value to month_string? I don't understand why it is not.

Comment: The indentations are correct in my python screen, they didnt cross over here, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this:

```
def get_date(date):
    month = date[5:7]
    month_string = None
    ...
```

`date[5:7]` is the `mm` part, while `date[4:7]` is `/mm`

Also, `month_string = None` handles the case the month is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your local variable is referenced before it is assigned is because `month_string` is not assigned in every case. Your last case where you assign it is an `elif` statement. Since Python doesn't know that your input values will only be those months, it cannot evaluate and be absolutely certain that the `month_string` is properly assigned before the `return` statement.

You can write `month_string = None` just before your first `if` statement.

```
def get_date(date):
month = date[5:7]
month_string = None
if month == "01":
    month_string = "January"
...
```